# Египтяне и афиняне

Tags: ударения

Интересно, есть ли ответ на  вопрос, почему надо говорить египтЯне, но афИняне? Но вопрос в другом. Кто из Вас говорит соответственно норме:афИняне. Никогда ни от кого я не слышала такого ударения в устной речи. Ни от своих учителей и вузовских преподавателей, ни от коллег учителей, ни в каких образовательных программах.  Более того, мне кажется, это неудобно в произношении: два похожих заударных слога.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не слышали, вероятно, потому что эти слова мы не так часто и произносим. Но мои преподаватели говорили именно так. Есть правило:

http://rusgram.narod.ru/328-379.html

Перед морфом -ан- чередуются: |л - л'| (село - селяне), |р - р'| (север - северяне, но Лютер - лютеране), |н - н'| (Двина - двиняне), |з - з'| (Тевриз - тевризяне), |т - т'| (Египет - египтяне, но Магомет - магометане), |к - ч| (Ессентуки - ессентучане), |г - ж| (Калуга - калужане), |х - ш| (Палех - палешане), |ц - ч| (Бронницы - бронничане, Кузнецк - кузнечане),  |с(с') - ш| (Котлас - котлашане, но Таруса - тарусяне с чередованием |с - с'|), |б1 - б1л'| (Витебск - витебляне), |м(м') - м1л') и т.д.

Ударение на предпоследнем слоге основы им. п. ед. ч. (акц. тип А), независимо от ударения мотивирующего слова: Волга - волжанин, -ане; хутор, -у, -ам - хуторянин, -яне; Ставрополь - ставропольчанин, -ане. Исключения: а) Рим -рИмлянин, Афины - афИнянин

А вот почему такое исключение - не в курсе.

Answer (score 2):

Это всё из-за стихотворения А.А. Ахматовой, в которое другой вариант ударения не помещался (смайлик):

Так вот когда царю приснился странный сон:

Сам Дионис ему снять повелел осаду,

Чтоб шумом не мешать обряду похорон

И дать афИнянам почтить его отраду.

"РИмлянин" - нормальное слово, а вот сказать  "афИнянин" без тренировки невозможно -  его бы хорошо использовать для отработки дикции в качестве упражнения. И если его нельзя произносить с другим ударением, то лучше вообще не произносить, чем ломать язык,что все и делают.

Answer (score 1):

Я стараюсь говорить по норме.

Comment: Вам часто приходится говорить о афинянах?))) Мне - нет. А когда приходится - заменяю на "жители Афин", "уроженец Афин" и т.п. Четко выговорить у меня не получается.

Comment: Я потому и написал "стараюсь", что нечасто.

Comment: Если,  первоначально  привыкнешь  к  "афИняне",  то  такое  ударение  кажется  естественным.  Правда,  это  у  меня  связывается  с  античностью.  Тогда  эти  афИняне  представляли  собой  что-то  особенное.  Случись  мне  разговаривать  о  жителях  современных  Афин,  то  не  исключено,  что  я  бы  произнёс  афинЯне.

Comment: >Правда, это у меня связывается с античностью  
  
Именно. Про современных как-то и не припомню, чтобы приходилось упоминать. Скорее всего сказал бы просто "жители Афин".

Comment: Карамзин поступал проще :  
>Н. М. Карамзин. Нечто о науках, искусствах и просвещении (1793) ... на печальных празднествах, учрежденных в память Павзанию и Леониду, убеждали и трогали сограждан своих, ― например, самые **афинцы удивлялись** красноречию спартанца Бразида и сравнивали его с лучшими из греческих ораторов.

Answer (score 0):

Первоначально в слове "египтянин" ударение тоже было на второй слог - "егИптянин". Посмотрите словарь русского языка XVIII века. Причем, это было единственное правильное ударение.

Comment: Делитесь информацией и переживаниями, не относящимися к Вопросу, в окнах Добавить комментарий!